# Является ли синтаксическая конструкция причастным оборотом?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Помогите разобраться с пунктуацией.
Мой друг (1) будучи человеком (2) склонным к анализу (3) решил все записывать в отдельную тетрадь.
Обособляется ли оборот "склонным к анализу"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что все запятые стоят на своих местах.

(1) Запятая обозначает начало деепричастного оборота.
[Будучи](https://www.anews.com/p/121385515-znachenie-slova-buduchi-chto-znachit-buduchi-primery-predlozhenij-so-slovom-buduchi/) — это деепричастие от глагола "быть".

(2) Запятая обозначает начало распространенного определения (не причастного оборота), стоящего после определяемого слова (человеком [каким?] склонным к анализу).
Склонный — это прилагательное ([словарь Ефремовой](https://znachenie-slova.ru/%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)).
[Обособленные определения](http://lingvotech.com/oo)

(3) Запятая закрывает деепричастный оборот (и определение тоже).

**Мой друг, будучи человеком, склонным к анализу, решил все записывать в отдельную тетрадь.**

*Будучи человеком, склонным к славе и признанию заслуг, он был совершенно нежадным* (коллектив авторов). *Стенли подумал, не будучи человеком, склонным к восторженным излияниям...* (Д. Голсуорси) *Будучи человеком, склонным к размышлениям, он вскоре устал от праздной жизни и обратился к религии* (Г. Б. Солдатова).

Comment: Спасибо. Меня смутило слово "склонный". Причастие легко определить по суффиксам: УЩ,ЮЩ,АЩ,ЯЩ, ЕНН, А+НН, Т, ВШ, Ш. Но в этом слове нет подобных суффиксов. -клон- - это же корень.

Comment: Инна, каюсь! Сейчас поправлю. Но все равно — обособляется.